# sql to list all tasks which are consumed high credits from WH credit quota

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am weak at snow sql, I want to list all tasks which are causing high credit usage from WH, credit quota from snowflake WH. any help on preparing snowsql ?

Comment: So which commands or system information table do you believe might have the information you are looking for?  Also what is “too much” is it a percentage. Is it 2 credits a day or 1000 credits a day?

Comment: Or you could calculate a percentage with Ratio_to_report

Comment: I have seated the Credit RM Quota for WH, which reseats at 1st of the month, normally WH credit quota gets full at the end of the month, but found one WH credit quota exhausted in initial days of the month. so wanted to know/list the tasks, which are consuming the high credit quota of WH from 1st till today's date.

Comment: so I typed "task credit usage" (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/search.html#q=task%20credit%20usage&t=All&sort=relevancy) into the help search and got: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-serverless-billing.html which points to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/serverless_task_history.html which the first example show how time time limit and per credits per task https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/serverless_task_history.html#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SERVERLESS_TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/serverless_task_history.html#examples) examples so pretty much this SQL (which I turned into a GROUP BY). Which is the first page searching the help for "task credit usage"  which seems to be your question.

```
SELECT start_time::date as day
    ,TASK_NAME
    ,sum(CREDITS_USED) as credits_used
FROM table(information_schema.serverless_task_history(
    date_range_start=>'2022-04-01 00:00:00.000',
    date_range_end=>'2022-04-04 00:00:00.000')
)
GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

I don't have any tasks so I have no output, but that should do the trick.