# Why am I unable to view the snowflake credits from the view - serverless_task_history?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have snowflake tasks scheduled that runs every hour that execute merge statements from a stream (based on raw table) to a curated table. I need to find the snowflake credits consumed by the task executions. I am running the following query as outlined [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722745/sql-to-list-all-tasks-which-are-consumed-high-credits-from-wh-credit-quota/71723268#71723268). However, I am not getting any records returned even if I remove the date conditions.

To double check, I ran a query on the task_history view (refer 2nd query below) and was able to view the records on the task executions.

Can someone help me understand why I am not able to view the credits consumption (from query# 1 listed below)? Is it because of I am missing any permissions or there is some issue with the query syntax?

```
    SELECT start_time::date as day
        ,TASK_NAME
        ,sum(CREDITS_USED) as credits_used
    FROM table(information_schema.serverless_task_history(
        date_range_start=>'2023-04-01 00:00:00.000',
        date_range_end=>'2023-04-28 00:00:00.000')
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

```
      select *
      from table(information_schema.task_history())
      order by scheduled_time;
```

Comment: If you query the snowflake.account_usage.SERVERLESS_TASK_HISTORY View do you see any records? Please can you update your question with the definition of a task that you expect to be running and consuming credits? Also, are you running this using the ACCOUNTADMIN role or a role with the MONITOR USAGE privilege?

Comment: I don't have ACCOUNTADMIN permissions. I am using a custom role.  When I run SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE <My-Custom-Role-Name> I see 700+ rows; These rows did not have the MONITOR USAGE in the result set.  How do I check if I have MONITOR USAGE privileges?

Comment: Hi, as asked by @NIckW when you query the   snowflake.account_usage.SERVERLESS_TASK_HISTORY  view, if you get a message " the the object dose not exist or not authorized "  then you don't have access to the MONITOR USAGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function information_schema.serverless_task_history returns results only for the ACCOUNTADMIN role or any role that has been explicitly granted the MONITOR USAGE global privilege.

If your role doesn't have MONITOR USAGE global privilege granted, then this function returns '0 rows'. The below command can help to check if this privilege is granted to your role or not.

```
 show grants to role <role_name>;
```

Comment: As mentioned in my above comment, when I run the below query I get over 700+ rows.  - SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE <My-Custom-Role-Name>.  The result has a column privilege = OWNERSHIP and granted_on = TASK in addition to many other privileges. However, there is no record where privilege = 'MONITOR USAGE'. Is this a confirmation that I don't have MONITOR USAGE permission?

Comment: Yes, this means the role <My-Custom-Role-Name> doesn't have the global privilege  MONITOR USAGE.

Comment: Thanks!!! Does granting MONITOR USAGE permissions also grant you access to monitor credit consumption for Serverless tasks as well tasks use customer provided warehouses?